# Query by field defined in interface

Tags: c#, generics, linq-to-sql

I have a couple of classes implementing an ISortable interface:

```
public interface ISortable
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    int? Idx { get; set; }
}
```

In my DbContext class I have an update method that should do some extra stuff for entities that implements the ISortable:

```
public void UpdateSingle<T>(T item) where T : class
{
    // If entity is Sortable, update the indexes of the records between the new and the old index of the updated entity
    var sortable = item as ISortable;
    if (sortable != null)
    {
        Detach(item);   // need to detach the entity from the context in order to retrieve the old values from DB
        var oldItem = Find<T>(sortable.Id) as ISortable;

        if (oldItem != null && sortable.Idx != oldItem.Idx)
        {
            var entities = FindAll<T>().ToList().Cast<ISortable>();

            var oldIdx = oldItem.Idx;
            var newIdx = sortable.Idx;

            if (newIdx > oldIdx)
            {
                var toUpdate = entities.Where(a => a.Idx <= newIdx && a.Idx > oldIdx).Select(a => a);
                foreach (var toUpdateEntity in toUpdate)
                {
                    toUpdateEntity.Idx = toUpdateEntity.Idx - 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var toUpdate = entities.Where(a => a.Idx >= newIdx && a.Idx < oldIdx).Select(a => a);
                foreach (var toUpdateEntity in toUpdate)
                {
                    toUpdateEntity.Idx = toUpdateEntity.Idx + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        Detach(oldItem);
        Attach(item);   // re-attach to enable saving
    }

    Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;

    Commit();
}
```

What I'm wondering about is this line:

```
var entities = FindAll<T>().ToList().Cast<ISortable>();
```

I have to convert the LINQ to SQL expression to a list in order to cast the entities to ISortable. And I need to cast it to ISortable in order to perform this Where:

```
var toUpdate = entities.Where(a => a.Idx <= newIdx && a.Idx > oldIdx).Select(a => a);
```

The Idx attribute is exposed by the interface.

The problem is that calling ToList() on FindAll() loads the whole table into memory.

Is there a way of performing the Where without first loading the whole table, and without losing the generic implementation?

The idea here is that I want to perform some common action on update for all entities that are "sortable". For this to work the update method needs to be generic in order to handle various classes, but then I need the interface to expose the necessary fields... If there's a better way of doing this (there probably is), please let me know. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that calling ToList() on FindAll() loads the whole table into memory.

Use `AsEnumerable` instead of `ToList`; it just changes the compile-time type to `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IQueryable<T>`, so the subsequent operations are executed in memory rather than in the database, but only one item at a time is processed (items are fetched from the DB one by one as needed by the subsequent operations).

Comment: Hi, would you care to elaborate on why AsEnumerable is better than ToList? I don't understand how loading records one by one is better than loading all at once, when all the rows need to be traversed anyway..

Comment: It's better in terms of memory usage, since only one item is present in memory at a time. In terms of performance, it doesn't make a big difference, since the filtering still has to be done in memory...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque While this is better, it's still far worse than being able to just do the query on the DB end, and that should be possible in this case.

Comment: @Servy, I agree, but I'm not sure it's possible to do it with the approach chosen by the OP...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Do you know of a different approach that would be better? I don't expect you to think up a whole solution for me, but if you could point me in the right direction it would be great :) I'm fairly new to .NET MVC, so the current solution is probably more a result of my ignorance than creativity.

Comment: @Stian, unless I misunderstood what you're trying to do, perhaps this kind of logic should be implemented in the DB itself (e.g. stored procedure or trigger), rather than in your app's code

Answer (score 0):

Trying again, this time with expressions. I think this should work:

```
public void UpdateSingle<T>(T item) where T : class
{
    // If entity is Sortable, update the indexes of the records between the new and the old index of the updated entity
    var sortable = item as ISortable;
    if (sortable != null)
    {
        Detach(item);   // need to detach the entity from the context in order to retrieve the old values from DB
        var oldItem = Find<T>(sortable.Id);

        if (oldItem != null && sortable.Idx != oldItem.Idx)
        {
            UpdateSingleSortable(oldItem, sortable);
        }

        Detach(oldItem);
        Attach(item);   // re-attach to enable saving
    }

    Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;

    Commit();
}

public void UpdateSingleSortable<T>(T oldItem, ISortable sortable)
    where T : class
{
    var entities = FindAll<T>();

    var oldIdx = oldItem.Idx;
    var newIdx = sortable.Idx;

    if (newIdx > oldIdx)
    {
        var expression = GenerateExpressionA(oldItem, newIdx, oldIdx);
        var typedExpression = expression as Expression<Func<T, bool>>;
        var toUpdate = entities.Where(typedExpression).Select(a => a);
        foreach (var toUpdateEntity in toUpdate)
        {
            toUpdateEntity.Idx = toUpdateEntity.Idx - 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var expression = GenerateExpressionB(oldItem, newIdx, oldIdx);
        var typedExpression = expression as Expression<Func<T, bool>>;
        var toUpdate = entities.Where(typedExpression).Select(a => a);
        foreach (var toUpdateEntity in toUpdate)
        {
            toUpdateEntity.Idx = toUpdateEntity.Idx + 1;
        }
    }
}

Expression GenerateExpressionB<T>(T t, int? newIdx, int? oldIdx)
{
    //    a => a.Idx >= newIdx && a.Idx < oldIdx
    var underlyingType = t.GetType();
    var idxGetter = underlyingType.GetProperty("Idx");

    Type genericFunc = typeof(Func<,>);
    Type[] typeArgs = { underlyingType, typeof(bool) };
    Type returnType = genericFunc.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

    var param = Expression.Parameter(underlyingType);
    var toReturn = Expression.Lambda(
        returnType,
        Expression.And
        (
            Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(
                Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, idxGetter),
                Expression.Constant(newIdx, typeof(int?))
            ),
            Expression.LessThan(
                Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, idxGetter),
                Expression.Constant(oldIdx, typeof(int?))
            )
        ),
        param);

    return toReturn;
}

Expression GenerateExpressionA<T>(T t, int? newIdx, int? oldIdx)
{
    //    a => a.Idx <= newIdx && a.Idx > oldIdx
    var underlyingType = t.GetType();
    var idxGetter = underlyingType.GetProperty("Idx");

    Type genericFunc = typeof(Func<,>);
    Type[] typeArgs = { underlyingType, typeof(bool) };
    Type returnType = genericFunc.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

    var param = Expression.Parameter(underlyingType);
    var toReturn = Expression.Lambda(
        returnType,
        Expression.And
        (
            Expression.LessThanOrEqual(
                Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, idxGetter),
                Expression.Constant(newIdx, typeof(int?))
            ),
            Expression.GreaterThan(
                Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, idxGetter),
                Expression.Constant(oldIdx, typeof(int?))
            )
        ),
        param);
    toReturn.Dump();

    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the `UpdateSingle` should also work for items that do *not* implement `ISortable`...

Comment: Thanks, but I got this error: `System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type ISortable is not part of the model for the current context.`

Comment: I tinkered with the code a bit. Try again? It should work. C# should know to assign the class type of `UpdateSingleSortable` to `T` and not `ISortable`.

Comment: I'm wrong its not. You would have to have the type constraint on `UpdateSingle` as well.

Comment: @Stian, entirely new answer. Try that.

Comment: @Shlomo Thank you very much for the effort! Unfortunately I get a null exception because the expression cast fails (`var typedExpression = expression as Expression<Func<T, bool>>;`)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the signature of the method to the following:

```
public void UpdateSingle<T>(T item)
    where T : class, ISortable
```

Then not only can you perform the query on the DB end (you won't need to pull the collection into memory to get the items meeting the given condition) you also won't be doing the check at runtime; you'll be checking to make sure `T` implements `ISortable` at *compile time*.

Comment: That won't work (already suggested by Shlomo), because ISortable is not part of the EF model